# Interval Partitioning of [0,1]

Tags: python, python-3.x, partitioning, partition

**Hey**, I want to Partition [0,1] into equal partitions with length of 0.05 in Python 3.

Comment: What?  Please rewrite the question properly.  Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to asking a question.

Comment: Your post is much more ambiguous than you seem to realize. "Partition [0,1] into equal partitions with length of 0.05" might seem clear to you, but it can actually be interpreted in a lot of different ways, depending on what kind of data structure you want to build or what kind of control flow you want to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps you mean a closed interval of [0,1]?

Comment: If you're having trouble seeing the ambiguity, try telling us more context. What goal does this partitioning serve?

Comment: I've generated 10000 pseudo-random numbers. I want to partition this interval into equal length intervals, and see how many random numbers thats been generated, fall in each partition. i will upload the image for this question. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension + `range()`

```
result = [x / 100 for x in range(0, 101, 5)]
```

**output**

```
[0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0]
```

Additionally, if you need all the numbers to be formatted with 2 digits after the point, then you can do: `"{:.2f}".format(x / 100)` instead of just `x / 100`

---

EDIT: For getting each interval of 0.05 — i.e: (0 ; 0.05), (0.05 ; 0.1), and so on — inside a list, we can use tuples as follows:

```
result = [(x / 100, (x + 5) / 100) for x in range(0, 100, 5)]
```

Which outputs:

```
[(0.0, 0.05), (0.05, 0.1), (0.1, 0.15), (0.15, 0.2), (0.2, 0.25), (0.25, 0.3), (0.3, 0.35), (0.35, 0.4), (0.4, 0.45), (0.45, 0.5), (0.5, 0.55), (0.55, 0.6), (0.6, 0.65), (0.65, 0.7), (0.7, 0.75), (0.75, 0.8), (0.8, 0.85), (0.85, 0.9), (0.9, 0.95), (0.95, 1.0)]
```

Comment: The `[*]` is pointless. You can iterate over a range directly.

Comment: Yes, I was trying something different first. Fixed. @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: thanks for your time, how can I make it seperate intervals like [0, 0.05) [0.05, 0.1) [0.1, 0.15) and so on?

Comment: No problem, let me update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy.linspace to split the range into equal parts

```
from numpy import linspace

r =[0,1]
slice_size = 0.05

# determine # of slices
n_slices =int((max(r)-min(r))/slice_size +1)
# split the range
print(linspace(*r, n_slices))
```